# How to display all user with their corresponding profile picture on admin home page?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am working on a project I want to display  users information  with their corresponding profile picture on admin home page.
I am using default User Model.

I use `userdata= User.objects.filter(is_superuser=False, is_staff=False)` to display all user information. it display user information as I want but my problem is that I am not able to display user  corresponding profile pictures

Profile model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)   
forget_password_token = models.CharField(max_length=100)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images",default="default/user.png")
def __str__(self):
   return f'{self.user} profile'
```

views.py code

```
def showallusers(request):
data= User.objects.filter(is_superuser=False, is_staff=False)
return render(request,"instructor/showallusers.html",{'data':data})
```

setting.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
 urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my user display  template is

```
<thead>
  <tr style="background-color:gray;">
  <th scope="col">ID</th>
  <th scope="col">Profile</th>
  <th scope="col">First Name</th>
  <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
  <th scope="col">Email</th>
  <th scope="col">Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>

 <tbody>
{% for userData in data %}
<tr>
  <th scope="row">{{userData.id}}</th>
    <td>here I want profile image of corresponding users</td>
  <td>{{userData.first_name}}</td>
  <td>{{userData.last_name}}</td>
  <td>{{userData.email}}</td>
  <td> 
   <a href="{% url 'dashboard:delete_user' userData.id %}"> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="window.mytest()">Delete</button></a>
   <script type="text/javascript">window.mytest = function() { var isValid = confirm('Are you sure to Delete this user?');
     if (!isValid) { event.preventDefault();  alert("It wont delete. Yay!");}}</script>

    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}


 </tbody>
```

I want to do like  [`this`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZlvh.jpg)

In the profile column I want to display profile picture of  corresponding user

Comment: Does `User.objects.filter(is_staff=False,is_superuser=False)` not filtering the user, you are not getting the result as shown by you in the picture, then show your template file how you are accessing it, or you want to show only single user clarify? And it's recommended to give `/` at the end of `upload_to` like this `upload_to='images/'`,  and in your template if you have to show image then you need to give `url` of image through something like `any_variable.image.url` in `src` of img tag, in loop.

Comment: thank you for your earlier responce Sunderam Dubey By using `User.objects.filter(is_staff=False,is_superuser=False)` i am able to print normal user information as I want like ID ,first_name ,last_name, Email, in a table but i also want to display their profile picture on that table. so please help me to print my desired result id ,profile picture ,Name ,email in a table

Comment: I am using Django default user model and my requirement is to displaye user information with their profile image on the template

Comment: Try one time `<td><img src="{{userData.image.url}}"></td>`, if this doesn't work check the images of user exist in `media` folder and also check whether uploaded correctly or not?

Comment: I have tried  <td><img src="{{userData.image.url}}"></td> but it does not show any profile picture. whereas user images are  exist in media folder

Comment: is there any way to filter profile picture like    profile_pic = Profile.objects.filter(is_superuser=False, is_staff=False)

Comment: It is attached with the `Profile` model. So no need to filter it separately.Can you update your question with current code you are trying? And also settings for media folder from `settings.py`.

Comment: now Iam able to display profile image with username and user id but it prints superuser profile information also but I don't want to print superuser profile information. is there any way to prevent to print superuser profile picture and username I want to print profile info of  normal users

Comment: Here is my code for views.py

   `pro=Profile.objects.all()
    return render(request,"instructor/showallusers.html",{'data':pro})`

templte code:
                                                                                                                                               
     `<th scope="row">{{userData.id}}</th>
        <td><img src="{{userData.image.url}}" width="40px" height="40px"></td>
      <td>{{userData.user.username}}</td>
     </tr>
    {% endfor %}`

Comment: now my problem is how to filter `is_superuser=Flase` while displaying profile info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to query `is_superuser=False` and not able to display image because you are filtering through inbuilt  `User` Model not your `Profile` Model, which has better relationship i.e. `OneToOne` relation with your `User` Model. You can simply query through `Profile` Model and get your work done in following way:

Try below code:

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)   
forget_password_token = models.CharField(max_length=100)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images",default="default/user.png")
def __str__(self):
   return f'{self.user} profile'
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . models import Profile
from django.db.models import Q


def showallusers(request):
    data = Profile.objects.filter(Q(user__is_superuser=False), Q(user__is_staff=False))
    return render(request, "instructor/showallusers.html", {'data': data})
```

**In the above view query is done through `Profile` model.**

Template file

```
<thead>
    <tr style="background-color:gray;">
        <th scope="col">ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Profile</th>
        <th scope="col">First Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Email</th>
        <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    
<tbody>
    {% for userData in data %}
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{userData.id}}</th>
        <td><img style="width: 40px; border-radius:15px;" src="{{userData.image.url}}" alt="this is it."></td>
        <td>{{userData.user.first_name}}</td>
        <td>{{userData.user.last_name}}</td>
        <td>{{userData.user.email}}</td>
        <td> 
            <a href="{% url 'dashboard:delete_user' userData.id %}"> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="window.mytest()">Delete</button></a>
            <script type="text/javascript">window.mytest = function() { var isValid = confirm('Are you sure to Delete this user?');
                if (!isValid) { event.preventDefault();  alert("It wont delete. Yay!");}}</script>
            
        </td>
        
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

> `Note:` The `userData.id` which is passed as `href="{% url 'dashboard:delete_user' userData.id %}"` to be deleted, will take the `id` from `Profile` model.

> `Note:` The `function` based views in django are written in `snake_case` so it would be better if the name of view changed to `show_all_users` from `showallusers`.